# How to create API based post types in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api, seo

I had tons of property entries in third party service ( these are all private ) and they provide API to get those property.

Now I want to show those property in my website like Custom post type with single/pretty-permalink

But, my main concern is SEO.

what is the best approach to create posts that not going to any issue about SEO?

I mean I understand if I created all the post as virtual URL then it won't be index to Search Engine neither robot will find out those property lists or links.

So, If I just create manually/automatically Custom post types post with just permalink and when that single is going to load I'm going to get all the single content using API then it would be ok to SEO?

Or you guys can give me any better Idea here. I can do the programming stuff just don't have enough knowledge about SE/SEO

Comment: I think you need to create a permalink structure like example.com/property/proerty-name

Comment: but I had similar plan first but is those link will be index by Search Engine robot? @Bhautik

Comment: Yes, those links will be index by the Search Engine robot.